# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > at index 4

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I having problem while building my project after revision 2 update of the latest SDK(Sorry,I dont remeber the version number).I run the code succesfully before. I dont think there is any error in my project.I often get error message as "IDE internal error occured" is that anything to do with this. please help thanks.Required codes are given below

**app/build.gradle:**

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.sleeko.board"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'

    compile('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

//    compile project(':Emojicon')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.alexbbb:uploadservice:1.4'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'

}
```

**Message Gradle Build:**

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAlexbbbUploadservice14Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk470Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubRahatarmanahmedCircularprogressview232Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubSatyanSugar13Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubTraexRippleeffectLibrary13Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMikhaellopezCircularimageview202Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareMeRelexCircleindicator115Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> at index 4
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 24.365 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

**Event log**

```
3:26:52 PM NullPointerException: Failed to set up Android modules in project
```

On clicking NullPointerException it says to report to google with details as below:

```
Failed to set up Android modules in project 'bridgewith'
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.toSystemIndependentName(FileUtilRt.java:207)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.toSystemIndependentName(FileUtil.java:634)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.getPlatformDir(AndroidSdkUtils.java:218)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.getPlatformAndAddOnJars(AndroidSdkUtils.java:122)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.getLibraryRootsForTarget(AndroidSdkUtils.java:156)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.setUpSdk(AndroidSdkUtils.java:409)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.createNewAndroidPlatform(AndroidSdkUtils.java:359)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.createNewAndroidPlatform(AndroidSdkUtils.java:336)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.createNewAndroidPlatform(AndroidSdkUtils.java:327)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.tryToCreateAndroidSdk(AndroidSdkUtils.java:617)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.customizer.android.AndroidSdkModuleCustomizer.customizeModule(AndroidSdkModuleCustomizer.java:92)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.customizer.android.AndroidSdkModuleCustomizer.customizeModule(AndroidSdkModuleCustomizer.java:48)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidGradleModelDataService.customizeModule(AndroidGradleModelDataService.java:330)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidGradleModelDataService.access$100(AndroidGradleModelDataService.java:88)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidGradleModelDataService$1.run(AndroidGradleModelDataService.java:159)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$Simple.run(WriteCommandAction.java:166)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:38)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$2$1.run(WriteCommandAction.java:114)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:931)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$2.run(WriteCommandAction.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:99)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:80)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidGradleModelDataService.doImport(AndroidGradleModelDataService.java:136)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidGradleModelDataService.importData(AndroidGradleModelDataService.java:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:132)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:102)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:141)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:148)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.Projects$1$1$1.run(Projects.java:130)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.mergeRootsChangesDuring(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:328)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.Projects$1$1.run(Projects.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:931)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.Projects$1.run(Projects.java:122)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeAndWaitIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2369)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.Projects.populate(Projects.java:115)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectSetUpTask$2.run(ProjectSetUpTask.java:113)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$7.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:369)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:569)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Looks like okay .You can try this `Clean-Rebuild -Restart-Sync Your Project`

Comment: I have tried it. but its not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the latest version of Android SDK build tools.

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

Good luck.

Comment: I fixed something similar using the same.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Then I tried the solution from [issue #195094](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195094) and it worked.

My problem likely was caused by the error I got while updating the sdk tools at the same time than Android Studio, trying to get both of them updated without closing AS beforehand. As a result, the SDK manager was marking the package as partially installed. After completely installing it, setting buildtoolsversion to 23.0.2, and then "invalidating caches and restart" the problem disappeared!

Comment: this is the same problem for me. any way got solved.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I noticed that Android 6.0 was partially installed. After completing download everything worked. It was hard to figure this because Android 6.0 was working before and then decided to try out the new emulator and downloaded system images and I guess loading those was not completed.

Answer (score 1):

> As you may have already found, this error can be visible due to many reasons. Hence you need to find actual reason behind the error.

Navigate to android folder and issue below command;

> gradlew --info clean build

This will list the actual issue, rectify that and redo the build.

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"
```

You will find this setting inside the file app/build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Based off the following log files:

"Failed to set up Android modules in project 'bridgewith'
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.toSystemIndependentName(FileUtilRt.java:207)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.toSystemIndependentName(FileUtil.java:634)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.getPlatformDir(AndroidSdkUtils.java:218)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.getPlatformAndAddOnJars(AndroidSdkUtils.java:122)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.getLibraryRootsForTarget(AndroidSdkUtils.java:156)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.setUpSdk(AndroidSdkUtils.java:409)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.createNewAndroidPlatform(AndroidSdkUtils.java:359)"

I think it's a problem with your Android Studio/Intellij IDE. Please uninstall Android Studio in your Programs and Features. Here:

[image]

Then reinstall Andriod Studio again. Go to Google's Android Studio download site and download and install the IDE.

I had a similar error and the problem came from a corrupt adb.exe file inside my user/android-sdks/platform-tools folder. So I had to delete my platform tools folder and then reinstall platform-tools using SDK Manager.